# Deploying a .net 4.0 application

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

I have an application built with .net 4.0 and uses WPF
My users have Windows 7 with default .net 3.5 installed.

My application cannot be downgraded to .net 3.5 and I want to avoid users from going through the process of downloading and installing .net 4.0 which is about 40MB (Even with silent install).

Since my application is a small one, is there a way to deploy it with only the required .net 4.0 libraries? and thus avoiding the installation of the entire .net 4.0 framework

If this is not possible, is there a way to execute the .net 4.0 app in a .net 3.5 environment?

Comment: Are you using any specific .net 4.0 features?

Comment: @Xero: But what aspects of WPF are you using that are specific to .NET 4?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using the Visual State Manager, I beleive there is no equivalent in .net 3.5?
Also i need support for Unicode 5.1, so i guess .net 4.0 is the answer, but i wanted check whether there was a way to include only the necessary .net 4 libraries, and run in a .net 3.5 environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If this is not possible, is there a way to execute the .net 4.0 app in a .net 3.5 environment?

No. Basically you really *need* to get the environments aligned. You say your application *cannot* be downgraded to .NET 3.5 - presumably that's because you're using something which is specific to .NET 4.0. It stands to reason that you can't then execute that in an environment which doesn't have .NET 4.0.

You need to decide which is more painful - changing your app to target .NET 3.5, or asking your users to install .NET 4.0.